# Get list of meridiems in MomentJs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) allows for multiple languages to be supplied to it in order to create locales for formatting and calculation.

They [specifically mention](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/) that some languages use more than two meridiems, and that there [are functions for returning lists of months/days](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) for a locale. Is there any way to return a list of the meridiems for the current locale?

Short of looping over 24 hours, calling `moment.localeData().meridiem(x)` for each hour and then looking for uniques i cant seem to find any documentation about it. Has anyone found a way to get this list, or is this something that I should request on their github?

Comment: Given the functional version of the customisation in 1.6.0+, I don't think you've got a choice other than to loop, including the minutes

Comment: i was afraid that was the case. Wasnt sure if there was something in the code base that hadnt made it to the docs that anyone knew about regarding fetching values from the locales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like looping is the only way

```js
let fn = moment().locale('zh-cn').localeData().meridiem,
    meridiems = new Set();
for (let hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
  for (let minute = 0; minute < 60; minute++) {
    // get both upper and lower cases
    meridiems.add(fn(hour, minute, true));
    meridiems.add(fn(hour, minute, false));
  }
}
console.log(Array.from(meridiems.values()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/locale/zh-cn.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have marked as the answer, unless some hail mary appears from their code base :)